# О толковании терминов "бытие" и "событие"

Tags: семантика

Верно ли, что:

1) бытие - это череда фактов, каждый из которых не привлекает внимание,

2) событие - это факт, который привлекает внимание?

Примечание (от 30.04.2014): По моим наблюдениям, в английском языке для описания событий (фактов, которые привлекают внимание) используется "время" Present Perfect Tense.

Answer (score 3):

Событие - это то, что со-путствует бытию. И верно сказано, что "жизнь - калейдоскоп событий".
С одной стороны, приставка "со" делает событие лишь составной частью бытия, как со-действие, со-авторство,со-трудничество, со-племенник... Но в нашем сознании устоялось уж так, что событие - это выдающееся свершение, или, как вы говорите, факт, привлекающий внимание. " Я пятёрку сегодня получил по русскому!" - "Ха! Тоже мне, событие! Вот если бы ты школу с красным дипломом закончил!.." На ваш вопрос, Галактион, я бы ответил: "Верно".

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется тут не совсем так. Бытие - вообще существование. БЫТЬ. Уже только от этого значения может формироваться идея будничного, сучного, ничем не выделяющегося существования. Событие - явление, которое СБЫВАЕТСЯ в определённое время. Опять же, значение какого-то особенного, выделяющегося явления приходит после. И бытие, и событие, происходят от нейтрального слова БЫТЬ, и сами по себе они нейтральны, но в разных контекстах могут принимать значения, указанные в вопросе.

Comment: По моим сведениям, событиями бывают не только явления, но и деяния.

Comment: Например, некогда событиями были убийство герцога Энгиенского в 1804 году и убийство эрцгерцога Фердинанда в 1914 году. Первое из указанные деяний способствовало началу очередной войны против Наполеоновской Франции, а второе - началу 1-ой Мировой войны.

Comment: Я пыталась подобрать слово, которое покрыло бы ВСЕ виды событий - и деяние, и разговоры, и то, что делаешь сам, и то, что делается другими (или никем/природой). Если Вы знаете более подходящее слово чем явление, подскажите пожалуйста, и я поменяю.

Comment: На мой взгляд, участник Неспящий дал хороший ответ на Ваш вопрос в теме "О вопросах к событиям".

Answer (score 1):

Слова «бытие и событие»  соотносятся с глаголом БЫТЬ, но при этом каждое из них имеет свое  собственное  значение, а также определенную стилевую характеристику и  область применения.

Бытие (книжн.) – это существование, жизнь, воспринимаемая как НЕПРЕРЫВНЫЙ процесс безо всяких ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫХ оценок.

Событие (нейтр.)  – это ФИКСИРОВАННЫЙ факт  (то, что свершилось), которое мы выделяем из непрерывного бытийного существования вследствие его ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНОСТИ для  личной или общественной жизни.

А вот как бытие и  событие изображаются  в поэтической форме:

«Чтоб бытия земного звуки Не замешались в песнь мою …» ( М. Лермонтов).
 «Уж карты весело порхают над столами, Целят скучающих, миря их с бытием» (Н. Гумилев). 
«Стихи – калейдоскоп красивых слов, А жизнь – калейдоскоп событий,  Печальных пауз, а потом пиров» (из соврем. поэзии).

Comment: Если каждое событие следует рассматривать как "фигуру" на "фоне", то как следует называть "фон"?

Comment: Чтобы понять соотношение бытия и события, можно БЫТИЕ (например, конкретного человека) представить в виде непрерывного графика «факт – время», где ПОВСЕДНЕВНЫЕ факты жизни составляют ПОСТОЯННЫЙ фон, а факты БОЛЕЕ ЗНАЧИМЫЕ определяются КАК СОБЫТИЯ меньшей или большей важности, получают название и тем самым  фиксируются нашим сознанием. Получится такая линия со «всплесками»  значимости, которые мы и называем событиями. (А вот приставка СО имеет значение не совместности события и бытия, а просто обозначает совершенный вид: быть – сбыться).

Answer (score 1):

Несколько соображений и дополнений к приведённым ответам.
Анализ семантики приставки "со/с" (Константин) -- это уже подход лингвиста (только начало его, конечно: есть и более сложные случаи: со-мнение, со-здание, и даже со-весть).
Другое полезное замечание: бытие = то, что бывает, вообще; событие = то, что сбылось, совершилось.
Отсюда шаг к замечанию в исходном вопросе, насчёт Perfect Tense.
Это наблюдение кажется очень тонким и ценным. Думаю, что можно провести параллель с (английским) определённым/неопределённым артиклем.

Comment: неопределённый артикль примерно равноценен словам "некий", "один", "любой", определённый: "этот/тот", "о котором речь", говоря словами Галактиона, "тот, на который направлено внимание".
Аналогично Indefinite Tense говорит, скорее, о том, что "бывает", а Perfect - о том, что сбылось, свершилось; потому оно и совершенное (или совершённое). Впрочем, здесь желателен комментарий носителя английского языка. Я не чувствую себя здесь достаточно компетентным

Comment: Большое спасибо за высказанное Вами мнение.

P.S. Если у Вас будет время, тогда взгляните на мой вопрос "Почему появились Словопоклонники?".